# Why forward referencing only possible in methods

Tags: java, variables, static

What is happening in the compiler when we do forward referencing methods, how does it assign the value of another variable which is not declared? And can we use that inside methods? But why can we not use the variable in static blocks? For example,

```
public class Forward {

    static int i = test();

    static int test() {

        System.out.println(j);
        j = 20;
        return j;
    }

    static {
        System.out.println(j);
        j = 20;
    }
    static int j;
}
```

If we assign the value directly like:

```
int i = j;
int j = 10;
```

Why does this code not compile? How is it possible only with methods? How does the compiler compile the forward references internally? Is the declaration happening first for all the variables and initialization happening next for all at a time or one by one? Explain it in detail.

Comment: "Explain in detail" did you read [JLS 8.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3)?

Comment: Thank you for your post. I read it, but i cannot get a clear picture about the flow. Is there any rule that we have to follow while using forward references. Can u explain it in  detail.

Answer (score 2):

[JLS Section 8.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3) states that 4 criteria must all be met if the forward-usage of a static variable will be considered a compile-time error:

> The declaration of a class variable in a class or interface C appears textually after a use of the class variable;

In other words, obviously, it must be a "forward declaration": you use it before you declare it:

```
// Maybe not OK to use j here.

static int j;

// OK to use j here.
```

> The use is a simple name in either a class variable initializer of C or a static initializer of C;

You can make a forward reference to the variable if you qualify its name:

```
static {
  System.out.println(j);                       // Error on this line...
  System.out.println(Forward.j);               // ...but not this line...
  System.out.println(org.whatever.Forward.j);  // ...or this line...
}
static int j;
```

This criterion *only applies to variable or static initializers*. This answers the specific question of why you are not getting a compiler error when referring to the static variable in a method.

However, let's just finish things off...

> The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;

Note in this code:

```
static {
    System.out.println(j);  // Error on this line...
    j = 20;                 // ...but not this line.
}
static int j;
```

You can't do anything except assign the variable, even if you reverse the order of the lines (you can't assign and then print it).

> C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use.

The following code would be fine:

```
class Forward {
  static class Inner {
    static {
      System.out.println(j);
    }
  }

  static int j;
}
```